# PySpark - Fill missing data with multiple columns as keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with 4 columns.

```
ts -> long (unix timestamp)
col1 -> string
col2 -> string
value -> long
```

the combination of `ts`, `col1` and `col2` is unique throughout my data. I want to fill missing data by creating rows with missing `ts`, `col1` and `col2` with all the combinations of the first 3 columns (`ts` has a specific range, `col1` and `col2` have a discrete list of values). They only way i could think of is to create a new dataframe with all the valid combinations of the 3 columns and set the `value` column to 0 and then somehow merging the 2 dataframes.
This is what i have so far

```
partial_data_df = spark.read.csv(my_path)

TS_DF = spark.range(min_ts, max_ts, 1000 * 3600).select(F.col('id').alias('ts')).orderBy('ts')
COL1_DF = spark.createDataFrame([..some data..], schema=['col1'])
COL2_DF = spark.createDataFrame([..some data..], schema=['col2'])
EMPTY_DF = TS_DF.crossJoin(COL1_DF).crossJoin(COL2_DF).withColumn('value', F.lit(0))

# now what?
```

How can i merge `partial_data_df` and `EMPTY_DF` on the 3 columns such that if the combination exists take the `value` column from partial_data_df and if it doesn't then put a 0? is there another way (more elegant) to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I tried to do a left join like so (I dropped the `value` column from the `EMPTY_DF` as suggested)

```
merged_df = EMPTY_DF.join(partial_data_df, (
                     (partial_data_df.ts == EMPTY_DF.ets) & 
                     (partial_data_df.col1 == EMPTY_DF.ecol1) &
                     (partial_data_df.col2 == EMPTY_DF.ecol2)
                    ), how='left')
         .select(
           F.col('ets').alias('ts'), 
           F.col('ecol1').alias('col1'), 
           F.col('ecol2').alias('col2'),
           F.when(((F.col('value').isNull()) | (F.col('value') == 0)), 0).otherwise(F.col('value')).alias('value')
         )
```

But the row counts didn't add up

```
row count in EMPTY_DF is 778176
row count in partial_data_df is 131709
row count in merged_df 778176
row count in merged_df that has non zero volume 100348
row count in partial_data_df that has non zero volume 131709
count distinct (ts, col1, col2) on partial_data_df 131709
count distinct (ts, col1, col2) on merged_df 778176
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the row count of `partial_data_df` with non-zero values?

Comment: @ggordon - please look at the updated row counts in the question - something is not adding up

Comment: it may be that some of the actual values did not match the generated values, eg if one of your actual `ts` values were `1 second off the hour` . Can you confirm whether these values exist using `partial_data_df.select(F.expr("CASE WHEN mod(value,1000 * 3600) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END").alias('is_not_consistent')).agg(F.sum('is_not_consistent'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You may continue by using

### Approach 1

...table aliases and the `when` function to use the value from the original dataframe if available. Using this approach you would not need to generate all possible empty values using `.withColumn('value', F.lit(0))` in memory as the cross join would result in a `NULL` which we could use

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

partial_data_df = partial_data_df.alias('original_df')
EMPTY_DF = EMPTY_DF.alias('empty_df')

final_df = EMPTY_DF.join(partial_data_df,(
    col('original_df.ts') == col('empty_df.ts') & 
    col('original_df.col1') == col('empty_df.col1') & 
    col('original_df.col2') == col('empty_df.col2') & 
),"left").select(
    col('original_df.ts'),
    col('original_df.col1'),
    col('original_df.col2'),
    when(col('original_df.value').isNull(),0).otherwise(col('original_df.value')).alias('value')
)

# Or Since both columns exist in both dataframes
final_df = EMPTY_DF.join(partial_data_df,['ts','col1','col2'],"left").select(
    col('empty_df.ts'),
    col('empty_df.col1'),
    col('empty_df.col2'),
    when(col('original_df.value').isNull(),0).otherwise(col('original_df.value')).alias('value')
)
```

### Approach 2

An alternative approach is using spark-sql eg.

```py
partial_data_df = partial_data_df.createOrReplaceTempView('original_df')
EMPTY_DF = EMPTY_DF.createOrReplaceTempView('empty_df')

final_df = sparkSession.sql("""
SELECT
    e.ts,
    e.col1,
    e.col2,
    CASE 
        WHEN o.value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE o.value
    END as value
FROM
    empty_df e
LEFT JOIN
    original_df o ON o.ts = e.ts AND 
                     o.col1 = e.col1 AND 
                     o.col2=e.COL2
""")
```

### References

- [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html)
- [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.when.html#pyspark.sql.Column.when)

Comment: Thank you - i tried to do this (ill edit the OP with my code) but the eventual row count doesn't match. i get that that merged_df has the exact row count of the `empty_df` (which is expected and good) but the row count of non 0 values in the `value` column is less than the row count of the `partial_data_df`.
Any idea why is this?